# Embedded google map on mobile devices, annoying button changing map size

Tags: css, google-maps, mobile, button

I have trouble making an embedded google map work properly on mobile devices. It is within a div box and set to 100% height/width and works as inteded when not on mobile phones. On phones it adds a big square-shaped button with an arrow in it in the bottom right corner which consequently shrinks the map size in the div to about half. When I click the mysterious button, nothing happens. So, an annoying button with no function. When I touch the map, the button disappears and the div is filled though. Anyway to get rid of that button?

Comment: Have you set disableDefaultUI to true in your config?

Comment: I am only using the easy-way copy/paste html code from google maps so I'm not sure where I would be able to change this?

Comment: Put some code in your question or we can't help you.